# Should I use Glassfish as an open source app server in the Enterprise to use with Spring or look at other options?

Tags: spring, jboss, glassfish

What is the best choice for an open source Enterprise-level application server when using Java 6 and Spring 3.1? Glassfish or JBOSS? Looking for good support e.g. online documentation, features, ease of use and set up, good performance, security, scalability, high availability features etc. that an enterprise would require. Enterprise being a large commercial or government client.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using EJBs? If not, I would recommend jetty. [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) is a very light-weight container for doing most of the exploration/testing you would want to do in a project. Another plus that jetty delivers is that it is configured with only the most basic features enabled/configured by default.

Are you using Maven? If so, I would also recommend jetty-maven-plugin. In the past, I've had some [success](http://active-active.blogspot.com/2011/04/maven-note-securing-temporary-jetty.html) with using the jetty-maven-plugin for local testing on a previous project.

Comment: No EJBs, just POJOs in a Spring container. This is to be used on a system used by 100k users. Is Jetty robust enough for that. I need high availability capabilities (load balancing plus failover etc).

Comment: @BestPractices: Sorry, misunderstood the original intent of your question. I'm not personally aware of issues with scaling jetty, but I'm sure that there are some resources out there for understanding the scalability of jetty. Perhaps start your investigations at [the jetty website](http://eclipse.org/jetty/). From there, I can see that jetty is used as part of the Yahoo Hadoop Cluster and Google AppEngine.